# Sync Outlook mail only leaving contacts not connected

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I've checked as thoroughly as I can and havent found a previous posting here or anywhere so here is my question:

I am using an Outlook Web App provided by a company which I work with on a independent contractor basis. I have that connected my Outlook 2007 on my home pc (win xp). I want to be able to send & received email using Outlook 2007 & the web app connected, which is working fine but I dont want all my contacts from Outlook 2007 and their notes showing up for them to have access to. Basically, is there a way to setup outlook to sync/share only mail and not my contacts or their info?? I really hope someone can help!